# Close command prompt window after opening file

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I have an Access application I'm running on a workstation that is used to monitor production on the floor.  The application refreshes data every minute or so, but for whatever reason it stops updating once or twice a day and sits.  I can catch the error, which means I can close the application when I see the error.  I have not been able to figure out why it stops updating/connecting but that's not the reason for my post.

I'd like to create a batch file I can run regularly to check if Access is open.  If it is, then do nothing, if it isn't, then open this data base file.  Here's the batch file right now:

```
@echo off
QPROCESS "MSACCESS.exe">NUL 2>NUL
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO :FIN
"C:\users\public\myfile.accdb"
exit
:FIN
exit
```

This works well for the most part.  If Access is running the batch file flashes and does nothing.  If Access is not running, the file opens up.  My problem is that if Access is not running and the file opens up, the command prompt window will hang open and sit there until the Access file is closed out.  I need the batch file to finish running after it opens the file, and then close out.

What am I missing?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps a `Start` command is required. Also, it may be worth considering starting `MSACCESS.exe` with your `.accdb` file as an argument, instead of relying upon the default handler for those extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Compo's reply to my question worked for me.I changed the line to launch the file to include a start command for MSACCESS.exe and then it worked and closed the window after running.

```
@echo off
QPROCESS "MSACCESS.exe">NUL 2>NUL
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO :FIN
start MSACCESS.exe "C:\users\public\myFile.accdb"
exit
:FIN
exit
```

Thank you!

Comment: You could reduce that to a single line [tag:batch-file] too, `@QPROCESS "MSACCESS.EXE">NUL 2>&1&&START MSACCESS "%PUBLIC%\MYFILE.ACCDB"`. From the [tag:command-prompt] you don't need the leading **`@`**.